# Sharing global variables across .cake files

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I use CAKE 0.21.1.0.

My `build.cake` script loads another `.cake` script: `tests.cake`.

I have defined some global variables in `build.cake` that I would like to use in both my `.cake` scripts.

Let's say I have a global variable named `testDllPath`.

When I use `testDllPath` in `tests.cake`, I see the following error:

> error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'testDllPath'

If I try to declare a new variable also named `testDllPath` in `tests.cake`, I see this error instead:

> error CS0102: The type 'Submission#0' already contains a definition for 'testDllPath'

How should I get access to the global variables defined in `build.cake` from another `.cake` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes if you load it after you declared it.

I.e. this won't work

```
#load "test.cake"
FilePath testDLLPath = File("./test.dll");
```

this will work

```
FilePath testDLLPath = File("./test.dll");
#load "test.cake"
```

A more elegant way is probably to have file with common variables and load that first i.e.

```
#load "parameters.cake"
#load "test.cake"
```

If you're trying to access a local variable from a static method or a class this won't work because of scoping.

In those scenarios you've got a few options

1. Pass variables to methods
2. Pass variables class constructors
3. Use public static properties/fields which will be accessible from anywhere.

The advantage of static/parameter usage us that load order won't matter.

#### Example local variable static method

```
File testDLLPath = File("./test.dll");

RunTests(testDLLPath);

public static void RunTests(FilePath path)
{
    // do stuff with parameter path
}
```

#### Example pass variable to constructor

```
File testDLLPath = File("./test.dll");

var tester = new Tester(testDLLPath);

tester.RunTests();


public class Tester
{
   public FilePath TestDLLPath { get; set; }       

   public void RunTests()
   {
       //Do Stuff accessing class property TestDLLPath
   }

   public Tester(FilePath path)
   {
        TestDLLPath = path;
   }
}
```

#### Example static properties

```
BuildParams.TestDLLPath  = File("./test.dll");

RunTests();


public static void RunTests()
{
    // do stuff with BuildParams.TestDLLPath
}

public static class BuildParams
{
   public static FilePath TestDLLPath { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, devlead! I loaded ``tests.cake`` after declaring the global variables, but nonetheless I still see the error message ``error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'testDllPath'``.

Comment: If you're using it in a class or static method you'll need to specify it as a parameter to that method, or have it as public  static properties/fields on a class. If you do that load order won't matter which is a nice plus.   You can see an example of that here: https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/develop/build/parameters.cake